# Proper cache setup with multiple servers

Tags: asp.net, caching, redis

We got 2 servers running an asp.net mvc application with simple load balancing. Both applications cache stuff at the moment with the system.runtime.caching. We want to move all of this to redis so we have 1 central cache instead of 2 servers each having their own.

It would be simple to just change the system.runtime.caching calls with redis calls. But how would one synchronize access to redis from 2 servers? One could lock a call to redis when a cache item is expired to load from database, but since there are 2 servers and hence 2 web apps this seems not possible.

We're playing with the idea of setting up a web api service for that to which both web apps communicate if they need a cached item. Is this the way to go? Or are there other solutions to consider?

I know it's a trivial question but I hope someone with experience could give us some pointers.

Comment: You might want to take a look at SqlCacheDependency: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604(v=vs.100).aspx